# Long press on a view using AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, testing, long-press, androidviewclient

How can I simulate long press on a view (for example a button) using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)? The touch method of `ViewClient` always performs a simple press on its input (even if I set *type* argument to **adbClient.DOWN**)

**Edit:**
The touch method in `adbclient.py` has a *type* argument, but it is not used in method body. In `MonkeyRunner`, when the type is **DOWN**, it performs longpress.

```
def touch(self, x, y, eventType=DOWN_AND_UP):
    self.shell('input tap %d %d' % (x, y))
```

Comment: Have you tried `longPress()` method instead of `press()`?

Comment: Yes. I test it but I don't know why it is similar to press() method.

Comment: Hm, let's ask @dtmilano. I just shared this to him via Google+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer for my question right now. We can use the drag method to simulate long pressing on views. The sample code is as follow:

```
buttonText = 'ClMe'
button = vc.findViewWithText(buttonText )
(x,y) = button.getXY()
button.device.drag((x,y), (x,y), 2000, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

From `adbclient.py`:

```
    version = self.getSdkVersion()
    if version >= 19:
        cmd = 'input keyevent --longpress %s' % name
        if DEBUG:
            print >> sys.stderr, "longPress(%s)" % cmd
        self.shell(cmd)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("longpress: not supported for API < 19 (version=%d)" % version)
```

Longpress is supported for API >= 19.

Comment: Thanks dtmilano. I think that this method is not applicable for buttons and other views. How can I simulate long-pressing on buttons using this?