# Simulate a long press on a view

Tags: androidviewclient

I am using AndroidViewClient.

I want to simulate a long press on a view . But unable to do so.

I have gone through :

[Long press on a view using AndroidViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120502/long-press-on-a-view-using-androidviewclient)

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use the drag method to simulate long pressing?

Comment: It works only for buttons,not for views I think.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701826/long-press-android

Comment: Drag works for views. How do you simulate a scroll with avc ? Any idea ?